# Return array of custom class objects from dictionary

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary

I have a super simple class I called a Tuple:

```
Private vals(1) As Integer
-----
Public Property Get x()

x = vals(0)

End Property
-----
Public Property Get y()

y = vals(1)

End Property
-----
Public Sub SetVals(x As Integer, y As Integer)

vals(0) = x
vals(1) = y

End Sub
```

I have a dictionary which is populated with arrays of these Tuples:

```
for x = whatever to whatever
   Set t = New Tuple
   t.SetVals somevalue, someothervalue
   ReDim Preserve tupleArray(x)
   Set tupleArray(x) = t
next x
theDictionary.Add someKey, tupleArray
```

I want to later retrieve the arrays from the dictionary but I'm struggling with it. Here's what I've tried

```
Sub DoStuffWithDictionary(dict as object, index as Integer)

Dim tupleArray() as Tuple

' Error: "Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object"
tupleArray = dict.Items(index)

' Error: can't assign to array
Set tupleArray = dict.Items(index)

' Error: same as above
Dim tupleArray as Object

' Error: same as above
Dim tupleArray as Variant

End Sub
```

Looping on the dictionary keys they all print out OK, I just can't get to the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example below:

On every dictionary key iteration, you need to loop the inner array as well.

**Tuple Class:**

```
Private vals(1) As Long

Public Property Get X() As Long
    X = vals(0)
End Property

Public Property Get Y() As Long
    Y = vals(1)
End Property


Public Sub SetVals(ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long)
    vals(0) = X
    vals(1) = Y
End Sub
```

**Test:**

```
Sub TestTuple()

    Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim t As Tuple
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long

    Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For i = 1 To 3
        For ii = 0 To 3
            Set t = New Tuple
                t.SetVals i + ii + 10, i + ii + 20
            ReDim Preserve arr(ii)
            Set arr(ii) = t
        Next ii
        d.Add CStr(i), arr
        Erase arr
    Next i

    Dim Key As Variant
    For Each Key In d.Keys
        For i = 0 To UBound(d(Key))
            Debug.Print "X: " & d(Key)(i).X, "Y: " & d(Key)(i).Y
        Next i
        Debug.Print ""
    Next
End Sub
```

Output:

```
X: 11         Y: 21
X: 12         Y: 22
X: 13         Y: 23
X: 14         Y: 24

X: 12         Y: 22
X: 13         Y: 23
X: 14         Y: 24
X: 15         Y: 25

X: 13         Y: 23
X: 14         Y: 24
X: 15         Y: 25
X: 16         Y: 26
```

**Edit:**

You can declare your array as Tuple if you wish. See below:

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim arr() As Tuple
    Dim t As Tuple
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To 4
        Set t = New Tuple
            t.SetVals i + 10, i + 20
            ReDim Preserve arr(i)
        Set arr(i) = t
    Next i

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print arr(i).X, arr(i).Y
    Next
End Sub

 '10            20 
 '11            21 
 '12            22 
 '13            23 
 '14            24
```

Comment: Thanks, good answer. Can you explain why tupleArray should be a variant and not the class? Also, I'm guessing then there's no way to reallocate the array in the dictionary to a new array outside of it?

Comment: See edit. You can declare the array as Tuple if you wish, and you get intellisense as well. I'm just used to the variant type when it comes to arrays. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access items by using the key:

```
Dim tupleArray As Variant
tupleArray = dict("someKey")
```